# Seperate data from different sources into lists of lists for analysis

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, binary

This code takes data from another program and looks into system drives, or any other drive, and looks to where the matching datasets may be found. This is needed since there are times when during analysis, we have to find the original datasets and copy over some missing files that were not copied in Powershell (for some reason or another). There are many drives on the system and many datasets.

The problem I am having is that each time the code produces a dataset for parsing (from one of the drives) it just appends the new dataset onto the end of the previous one. I have been trying to separate each new list into a list of lists but have not had any success. It scans each drive very well but the appending is the issue I am dealing with in this code. Either way, I just need to analyze the dataset from each drive separately.

```
def binarySearch():
    n = 0
    groupList = []
    dataList = [] ## tried making list of lists using this list
    setFolder = []
    driveList = []
    driveList.append('Z:\\\\')
    driveList.append('Q:\\\\')
    driveList.append('H:\\\\')
    driveList.append('E:\Test Search')
    for drives in driveList:
        groupList.append(drives)
    print groupList
    for items in groupList:
        os.chdir(items) ## creates a list of lists for each drive
        print 'Scanning drive:',os.getcwd()
        for line in os.listdir(items):
            if len(line)==3 and line != 'sec':
                setFolder.append(int(line)) ##appends new dataset to old one
        setFolder.sort()
        n = n + 1
        continue
```

Im pretty certain something needs to happen with this line of code:

```
 setFolder.append(int(line)) ##appends new dataset to old one
```

To where it creates a new list from within the existing list setFolder. Or if I could create a new list all together with each iteration that could also work.

Comment: Have I done a terrible job of presenting this causing there to be no replies? If so (most likely), what can I do to get replies on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only ever appending to `setFolder`, never adding to `dataList`. You probably want to do something like

```
for items in groupList:
    setFolder = []
    os.chdir(items) ## creates a list of lists for each drive
    print 'Scanning drive:',os.getcwd()
    for line in os.listdir(items):
        if len(line)==3 and line != 'sec':
            setFolder.append(int(line)) ##appends new dataset to old one
    setFolder.sort()
    dataList.append(setFolder)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but while that does create a list of data within setFolder it does not keep dataList from being appended with each iteration. So on the second iteration, or the second drive, it has both the data from the first and second iterations.

Comment: Did you put the `setFolder = []` line inside the `for items in groupList:` loop?

Comment: That just seems to have a similar problem.

Comment: I think I just solved it. But moving the setFolder list into the groupList loop was half the problem. The other half was just indentation. I needed to indent the rest of the code one indentation to the right below the driveList loop. How silly. Thank you very much ill give you credit since you helped me and I didn't get much love today.